# How to Get All sheets in a workbook to one - Excel 2013

Tags: excel

is it possible to automatically get all the sheets in workbook to a new sheet ?

i converted an PDF file(29page) to excel 
it is successful done, but i got 1 page as 1 sheet (so totally 29 sheets)

is there any option in excel to combine all those sheets to sheet.

Comment: Yeah...its possible, you should probably do some research on google and comeout with some codes - try it out, if your in problem then come to SO with the code and possible identified error...thats how things work on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by writing simple macro for that workbook

Introduction to write macro.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/introduction-to-custom-macros-in-excel-HA001118958.aspx

```
Dim offsetRow As Integer
```

---

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tmpws As Worksheet
offsetRow = 3
lastrow = 1
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
 s = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index
For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Cells(lastrow, 1).Select
    lastrow = lastrow + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count + offsetRow
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Paste
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select
    'ThisWorkbook.Application.SendKeys ("{ESC}")
Next i
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Tushar, thanks for taking time to reply this :) but sorry i have no idea about this. if you have a min for me... can you please help me in this...

Comment: I have provided a link for that.

Comment: If you want more help in writing macro for your workbook you can share your worksheet structure to me on my personal email id. I will help you to write macro for that.

Comment: thanks :-)  please see this screen shot.. http://snap.ashampoo.com/GgoUHEnq all the pages have same structure .

Comment: thanks for taking time :) its solved now. your link helped me :)